# Apache Airflow Connection hook is instantiating multiple connection

Tags: airflow

Background: Apache Airflow documentation reads:

> Hooks Hooks act as an interface to communicate with the external
> shared resources in a DAG. For example, multiple tasks in a DAG can
> require access to a MySQL database. Instead of creating a connection
> per task, you can retrieve a connection from the hook and utilize it.

I have tried spawning 10 tasks using different DB: MYSQL, POSTGRES, MONGODB. Please note that I am using one DB (ex: MYSQL) in one DAG (consisting of 10 tasks).
But, All tasks are instantiating a new connection.

Example of my task:

```
conn_string = kwargs.get('conn_id')
pg = PostgresHook(conn_string)
pg_query ="...."
records = pg.get_records(pg_query)
```

why is airflow instantiating a new connection when airflow documentation itself reads (..... multiple tasks in a DAG can require access to a MySQL database. Instead of creating a connection per task, you can retrieve a connection from the hook and utilize it...........)

What is being missed here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what they mean to say with that part of documentation is that hooks prevent you from redefining the same credentials over and over again. With connection, they are referring to an Airflow connection you define in the web interface and not an actual internet connection to a host.

If you think about it this way:

- A task can be scheduled in any of the 3 airflow worker nodes.
- Your 10 tasks are divided between these 3.

How would they be able to share the same internet connection if it comes from different hosts? It would be very very hard to maintain those internet connections across workers.

But don't worry, it also took ages for me to understand what they meant there.

Comment: Thanks. I don't have 3 worker nodes corresponding to 3 DB. I am using just one DB (say MYSQL) in a DAG. Now, in this DAG, I have  10 task which will use DB (=MYSQL). Each of this task is instantiating separate connection why? is there any way to avoid it?

Comment: Unfortunately not, my example was to indicate that it is technically (almost) impossible to make it work. In a lot of setups (not yours) these 10 tasks you are talking about, can be executed on different servers. It's not possible to share these sessions between different servers. Hence, there is no way we can reliably implement the sharing of this session. 
Conclusion: Technically impossible to make it share the same physical internet connection.